# Synapse and Spark - Exporting Dataframe to CSV

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse

We receive a set of monthly files in CSV format from a provider which include a number of columns which "bloat" the dataset and a large number of duplicates.  They provide this to multiple customers, so them removing them is not an option and they are resolving the duplicate issue.

Reading and processing the file is very straight forward. I use select on the end of the read command to only select the fields I required (remove in this example) but when I write the dataframe back to a CSV file, I cannot work out how to get the text qualifiers (") to appear around the string and not to change the format of the output.

Using the code below, it works, apart from adding a NULL in front and after the "D,E" in the second column.  The file then fails to load.  I then tried to remove the ","'s from the file, but this would convert the example to DE, so that is not really a solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

J

```
IDAppointment,IDOrganisationVisibleTo,IDPatient,DateStart
1,"A",101,2023-07-31 10:35:00.0000000
2,"B",102,2023-08-03 11:42:00.0000000
3,"C",103,2023-09-13 12:10:00.0000000
4, "D,E" ,104,2023-08-01 17:10:00.0000000
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9jTp.png)

```
file_df = spark.read.options(delimiter=',', header=True, nanValue = None, inferSchema = True, quote = '"').csv(full_input_path)

# Add double quotes around string columns - to create the text qualifier
for col_name, dtype in file_df.dtypes:
    if dtype == 'string':
        file_df = file_df.withColumn(col_name, F.concat(F.lit('"'), F.col(col_name), F.lit('"')))

file_df = file_df.dropDuplicates(primarykey)

file_df.write.option("header", "true").option("quote", "\u0000").mode("overwrite").csv(full_output_path, sep=',')
```

```
**ORIGINAL FILE**
IDAppointment,IDOrganisationVisibleTo,IDPatient,DateStart
1,"A",101,2023-07-31 10:35:00.0000000
2,"B",102,2023-08-03 11:42:00.0000000
3,"C",103,2023-09-13 12:10:00.0000000
4,"D,E",104,2023-08-01 17:10:00.0000000

root
 |-- IDAppointment: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- IDOrganisationVisibleTo: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IDPatient: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- DateStart: timestamp (nullable = true)

+-------------+-----------------------+---------+-------------------+
|IDAppointment|IDOrganisationVisibleTo|IDPatient|          DateStart|
+-------------+-----------------------+---------+-------------------+
|            1|                      A|      101|2023-07-31 10:35:00|
|            2|                      B|      102|2023-08-03 11:42:00|
|            3|                      C|      103|2023-09-13 12:10:00|
|            4|                    D,E|      104|2023-08-01 17:10:00|
+-------------+-----------------------+---------+-------------------+
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Hi, good point. In this instance it would be exactly the same as the input file.  In the real scenario, the output would have less columns.  so the table at the top has "extra null" characters around the "D,E" - see attached image as it's hard to explain.   https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9jTp.png

Comment: So you need null values around D,E when the column removed? Give me your select query.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not being very clear.  The input file looks like this

4,"D,E",104,2023-08-01 17:10:00.0000000

The output file looks like this, with the extra spaces (acutally null values not spaces)

4, "D,E" ,104,2023-08-01 17:10:00.0000000

Answer (score 0):

You use below python code to remove those whitespace or null.

Below is the result when i tried on your result data
that is having nulls or spaces.

[image]

So, using below code i removed it.

```
import csv

input_file = '/dbfs/mnt/dynamics/samp/mall_csv.csv'   # Replace with your input CSV file name
output_file = '/dbfs/mnt/dynamics/samp/mall_csv_new.csv' # Replace with your desired output CSV file name

with open(input_file, 'r') as csvfile, open(output_file, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in csvfile:
        csv_string = line.replace(", ", ",").replace(" ,", ",")
        print(csv_string)
        outfile.write(csv_string)
```

Apply above code on your output file whichever you are getting nulls or spaces.

[image]

Output:

[image]